# iOS playing many audio files EXACTLY at the same time

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I have 91 audio files that I need to be able to play simultaneously, and here's what I tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++){
    [(AVAudioPlayer*)audioPlayers[i] prepareToPlay];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++){
    [(AVAudioPlayer*)audioPlayers[i] play];
}
```

When I use this, I think there's a slight delay after playing each sound, so they don't play quite at the same time.

How can I play them exactly at the same time?

I thought of combining them into a single file and then playing it, but I'm not sure how to implement this approach or if it's even the right approach.

Comment: use prepareToPlay method of AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: @KumarUtsav My bad, I forgot to include it in the question, but I'm already using it.